# Why is my while statement not working

Tags: python

I am relatively new to programming and am having trouble with a simple while loop. I am attempting to write a program that outputs all multiples of 3 between 0 and 100. Here is what I have:

```
counter3 = 1
theList = []

while counter3 <= 1000:
   if 3 % counter3 : True
   theList.append(counter3)
   counter3 = counter3+1


print(theList)
```

The while loop I am using has a syntax error, but I am not sure where it is. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help to learn how to properly format your question.

Comment: The syntax error should literally have a dashed line and a `^` that points to the exact place in your code that has the error.

Comment: Your code says: If counter3 mod 3 is trueish, then `True`. And that simply does nothing.

Comment: By the way, if I copy/paste your exact code into a `test.py` file and run it, Python 2.7 and 3.6 do not give a syntax error. The modulo doesn't work so they both just output all 999 numbers, but no errors.

Answer (score 2):

When the code you used is ran, it does not throw a syntax error. It instead returns a list of the numbers from 1 to 1000. The reason why is the following statement:

```
if 3 % counter3 : True
theList.append(counter3)
```

The `:` operator denotes the end of the `if` statement, and what is placed after that is executed if the statement is true. In this scenario, you would want to replace the `:` with a `==`. Since the if statement is executed automatically if `3 % counter3` is true, then you don't need `== true` at all.

Then, you would want to indent `theList.append(counter3)`, so that it runs if the statement is true. New code:

```
counter3 = 1
theList = []

while counter3 <= 1000:
   if 3 % counter3:
       theList.append(counter3)
   counter3 = counter3+1


print(theList)
```

However, it still prints the numbers from 1 to 1000. This is because the numbers used in the `%` operator are on the wrong sides. You want to check if the number is divisible by 3, using the line `if counter3 % 3:`.

Now it prints everything *except* numbers divisible by 3. This is because a number divisible by 3 will return 0. 0 is a falsy value, which means it evaluates to false in the `if` statement. 1 and 2 (the other options) evaluate to true.

Falsy values are `False`, `0`, `[]`, `""`, `0.0`, `0j`, `()`, `{}`, and `set()`.

Check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983695/what-is-truthy-and-falsy-in-python-how-is-it-different-from-true-and-false) for details.

Since you want to check if it is divisible by 3, then you want to check if the number mod 3 is equal to 0. Now your code is the following:

```
counter3 = 1
theList = []

while counter3 <= 1000:
    if counter3 % 3 == 0:
        theList.append(counter3)
    counter3 = counter3+1


print(theList)
```

You could do `if not counter3 % 3`, as 0 is falsy, but that obscures the function of your code and is not a good practice.

Since your question says to do numbers between 0 and 100, you should change the while statement to `while counter3 <= 100:`.

Another thing is that you should probably use a `for` loop. This lets you iterate over a `range`, allowing you to not have to keep track of the variable and increment it over time.

```
theList = []

for counter3 in range(1, 100):
    if counter3 % 3 == 0:
        theList.append(counter3)


print(theList)
```

This code works, and it observes most best practices.

If you wanted to, you could use a list comprehension for a one-liner, but this wouldn't be needed.

```
print([i for i in range(1, 100) if i % 3 == 0])

print([i * 3 for i in range(1, 34)]) #Prints first 33 numbers multiplied by 3, has the same result.
```

Answer (score 0):

To tell if a number is a multiple of three, it should be

```
if counter3 % 3 == 0:
```

`counter3 % 3` computes the remainder of `counter3 / 3`, and this remainder is `0` for exact multiples.

Then you need to indent the statements that should be executed when this condition is true.

So the loop should be:

```
while counter3 <= 1000:
    if counter3 % 3 == 0:
        theList.append(counter3)
    counter3 = counter3+1
```

Instead of a `while` loop, you can use `for`:

```
for counter3 in range(1, 1001):
    if counter3 % 3 == 0:
        theList.append(counter3)
```